How could I prevent using the same custom loop in a template file when I only need to change one meta_query parameter?
I am displaying a set of upcoming fixtures for two cricket teams on the same page. The fixtures are created from a CPT and the relevant team is selected from a custom field.
I have everything working as I would want but, I have custom loops set up and the only difference between the two is one key => value pair.
          $firstXIFixtures = new WP_Query(array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'fixture',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                'key' => 'team',
                'compare' => '==',
                'value' => '1st_XI',
                'type' => 'text'
              ),
            ),
          ));

I only need to change 'value' => '1st_XI' to 'value' => '2nd_XI' in the next loop.
If it helps to give context, the fixtures are in a two column layout with separate headings above to indicate which teams the below fixtures are for.

How do I make this template file a little cleaner as it feels quite repetitive?

You could define an array $fixture = array ('1st_XI','2nd_XI') and loop through that, like this:
foreach ($fixture as $value) {
  $firstXIFixtures = new WP_Query(array(
  ...
    'value' => $value,
  ...));

  ... the html you use to display the column

}


thank you for your feedback. although I didn't use this solution in the end, it prompted me to think differently and I have now wrapped the custom query in a function that has the parameter $team. I have tried to find other examples of custom queries being used like this and didn't find much so I am left wondering why...

I don't understand why you don't use cjbj's proposition ? what is "it" in "it prompted me to think differently" ?
